# Use HTTP proxy with Savon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, savon, proximo

I need to access a service with an IP whitelist from Heroku, necessitating the need for an HTTP proxy.

I configured the Proximo add on, and have a proxy url that looks approximately like `http://proxy:secret-key@proxy-0-0-0-0.proximo.io`

In Savon, I have tried configuring a proxy like so:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: my_wsdl, proxy: "http://proxy:secret-key@proxy-0-0-0-0.proximo.io")
```

But when I make a request:

`client.operations`

I get a proxy error:

```
Wasabi::Resolver::HTTPError: Error: 407 for url http://mywsdl
        from /Users/ahamon/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/wasabi3.5.0/lib/wasabi/resolver.rb:45:in `load_from_remote'
        from /Users/ahamon/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/wasabi3.5.0/lib/wasabi/resolver.rb:33:in `resolve'
        from /Users/ahamon/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/wasabi3.5.0/lib/wasabi/document.rb:142:in `xml'
        from /Users/ahamon/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/wasabi-3.5.0/lib/wasabi/document.rb:160:in `parse'
        from /Users/ahamon/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/wasabi-3.5.0/lib/wasabi/document.rb:147:in `parser'
        from /Users/ahamon/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/wasabi-3.5.0/lib/wasabi/document.rb:64:in `soap_actions'
        from /Users/ahamon/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/client.rb:28:in `operations'
        from (irb):7
        from /Users/ahamon/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from /Users/ahamon/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /Users/ahamon/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /Users/ahamon/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /Users/ahamon/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Everything works just fine without the proxy option, though.

Comment: I think the user:password@url syntax works only in a browser. You can try basic authentication.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Savon docs don't specify how to configure the proxy further (in version 2) @SteffenRoller

Comment: I think because the proxy connectivity is a function of the underlying http module which can differ. Use the source, Luke!

Comment: Source diving as we speak :)

Comment: httpclient knows about proxy authorization: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.1.5.2/HTTPClient/ProxyAuth. You might need to check in the code where to apply it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found a solution.
The inconvenience is to fetch the WSDL manually and to save it into a local file.
Eg.

```
curl http://www.webservicesx.net/globalweather.asmx?wsdl > globalweather.wsdl
```

You have to add the following to your client definition

```
...
secret = Base64.strict_encode64("#{user}:#{password}")
client = Savon.client(
    wsdl: 'globalweather.wsdl',
    proxy: "http://my-proxy.example.com:8080",
    headers: { "Proxy-Authorization" => "Basic #{secret}" },
    ...
)
```

That's basically it.
You can also work completely without WSDL by specifiying `namespace` and `endpoint` directly.

Savon uses Wasabi to process the WSDL. It also fetches the document from the server. Wasabi doesn't use the parameters from Savon's client definition. To change it one would have to extend the Wasabi gem.

A running script can be found here: http://pastebin.com/t8NTuGKK.

Comment: Hey Steffen, I'll check it out! I tried setting Proxy-Authorization in the header previously, but without downloading the WSDL separately.

Comment: Ha - I won my first bounty - whoo hoo :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: my_wsdl, proxy: "http://proxy-0-0-0-0.proximo.io", basic_auth: ["proxy-user", "proxy-secret"])
```

Comment: basic_auth [appears to be a configuration option for accessing the SOAP resource, not the Proxy](http://savonrb.com/version2/globals.html). Either way, I tried it to no avail.